# Android how to align headings to listview items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, alignment, android-linearlayout

I have a Listview in my application, Which I am trying to put a head for each 'Coloumn' however I cant get them to align correctly.

I have made the heading linearlayout items the same layout params as the listView items but they still dont align.

Here is an example app I made to demonstrate the issue.

[image]

I have enabled the developer boarder lines so you can easily see how its not aligned.

Here is the list view display item:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rhinoZoneDisplayItem_textView_zoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:text="1:"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rhinoZoneDisplayItem_textView_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Status"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

and the headings linear layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Zone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Status"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your doing is correct when your using Layout-Weights make sure you set the width as "0dp" rather than wrap-content. So as to get all Heading and list view items to align correctly and give equal weights for each column.

Comment: That then causes some of the text in the heading to fall over to the next line.

Comment: Are you giving the same width for both header and the list view columns. If yes and still the Header falls over then you have correct that programmatically or reduce the font size of the header text.But when using layout weights the best practice is to keep width or height attribute to 0dp, so as to get the width of column uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `match_parent` for `TextView` width.

Comment: Also, post the full xml for both layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can put in each item of the list the same value for the field

```
android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
```

this is just an example of the value, in this way all the elements are aligned on left side.